# Where is my custom log files in Dokku rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dokku

Where i can find my rails application custom logs?

For example:

```
efrsb_log ||= Logger.new("#{Rails.root}/log/get_trade_messages.log")
efrsb_log.error('No content in response')
```

On the local machine I can see them in exact location in application's container.
But on production server I see nothing in log folder.

Does dokku write all logs into its own one file?

If so how can i separate different log information?

Comment: Look at this path: `/var/lib/dokku/data/storage/your-app-name/log/production.log`

Comment: @demir `/var/lib/dokku/data/storage` is empty

Answer (score 1):

If you need to manage logs on a dokku app in production its better to handle them on an  syslog cloud service like papertail (In my experience the best interface for logging so far and it will not break your wallet).

For do that you need to install a plugin to export your logs.

1) Install dokku-logspout

```
dokku plugin:install https://github.com/michaelshobbs/dokku-logspout.git
```

2) Point logspout to your PaperTrail syslog endpoint:

```
dokku logspout:server syslog+tls://logs.papertrailapp.com:12345
```

Make sure your PaperTrail endpoint is configured to accept TLS connections.

3) Install dokku-hostname:

```
dokku plugin:install https://github.com/michaelshobbs/dokku-hostname.git dokku-hostname
```

This will ensure that the host in your PaperTrail logs use the heroku-like name of your worker instead of the docker container ID.

4) Run dokku logspout:start and use logspout:stream to ensure that your logs are being aggregated properly.

Here’s a couple issues you may run into::

- You may need to rebuild your apps for them to start piping to logspout. dokku ps:rebuildall
- When you re-deploy your apps, the heroku-like program names will be lost. To fix this run dokku logspout:stop && dokku logspout:start. Hopefully this issue will be fixed soon.
- docker ps returns a daemon error. Run sudo usermod -aG docker ubuntu && sudo reboot as ubuntu.

Source from "[Mike Bianco](http://mikebian.co/sending-dokku-container-logs-to-papertrail/)"